# Task Dataflow, can a data block be changed from completion state?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I would like to know whether it is possible to change the completion state of data blocks?

For example, I marked a `var block = new BufferBlock<int>();` data block complete with `block.Complete()`. The block is linked to other data blocks. I would like to know whether I can make `block` run again by changing its completion state back to its original !complete state.

If that is not possible how could I perform multiple runs, including completion, without having to a) de-link all blocks, b) re-instantiate all blocks,and c) re-link all blocks again?

Any ideas which may ease the task of running data flow cycles including completing each block down the chain without having to re-create the whole framework?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you even need separate runs? Also, why don't you want to recreate the dataflow network? I doubt it's going to affect performance (unless you do that many times per second) and it also shouldn't make your code more complicated by much.

Comment: The separate runs are part of the requirement. Re-creating the whole network would completely defeat the efficiency gained through choice of tpl dataflow. The main headache is the unlinking and relinking not so much the re-creation of each data flow block. If changing the completion state is impossible how could I otherwise signal completion without affecting the completion state of each data flow block? I cannot just send an atomic flag because the object types down the chain are not identical (there are transformblocks involved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't “uncomplete” a completed dataflow block. I think what you should do is to add a flag to each message that says whether it's last message in a run. To make it simpler to work with it, you could create set of helper methods like:

```
public static TransformBlock<Tuple<TInput, bool>, Tuple<TOutput, bool>>
    CreateEnhancedTransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>(Func<TInput, TOutput> transform)
{
    return new TransformBlock<Tuple<TInput, bool>, Tuple<TOutput, bool>>(
        tuple => Tuple.Create(transform(tuple.Item1), tuple.Item2));
}
```

This way, you enter a `transform` delegate that deals just with `TInput` and `TOuput` and the flag is transfered along with each message.

Comment: Interesting idea, would you care to comment on computational overhead during execution by going this route? So far I only see an additional check on the "completion flag" of the receiver block for each incoming message. Anything else I am omitting? Would it be more expensive to instead ship an enum rather than bool? In that way I could communicate other states than just completion.

Comment: @Freddy There could be some tiny overhead since there are two delegate invocations instead of one, but that should be really negligible. And I think replacing the `bool` with an enum shouldn't affect the performance either.

Comment: definitely a good idea to solve this issue, but in the end I went with your first advice: I peruse the neat completion feature of data blocks and re-create the whole pipeline. I provide callbacks to upstream data block containing modules and upon the completion of each data block it re-creates the same and hands it through the callback downstream where the two blocks are re-linked.

Comment: I also find adding an indexing system to be helpful for identifying runs or batches of data.  This makes it so that the runs do not need to be completely isolated.